# Missing one coloumn from my table sql

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, datatables

I have this data from `print_r()`. Here is the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Customer
    [1] => 01/08/2016
    [2] => 02/08/2016
    [3] => 03/08/2016
    [4] => 04/08/2016
    [5] => 05/08/2016
    [6] => 06/08/2016
    [7] => 07/08/2016
    [8] => 08/08/2016
    [9] => 09/08/2016
    [10] => 10/08/2016
    [11] => 11/08/2016
    [12] => 12/08/2016
    [13] => 13/08/2016
    [14] => 14/08/2016
    [15] => 15/08/2016
    [16] => 16/08/2016
    [17] => 17/08/2016
    [18] => 18/08/2016
    [19] => 19/08/2016
    [20] => 20/08/2016
    [21] => 21/08/2016
    [22] => 22/08/2016
    [23] => 23/08/2016
    [24] => 24/08/2016
    [25] => 25/08/2016
    [26] => 26/08/2016
    [27] => 27/08/2016
    [28] => 28/08/2016
    [29] => 29/08/2016
    [30] => 30/08/2016
    [31] => 31/08/2016
)
```

I'm using `CodeIgniter` above is the `fieldname` from my table. Then I'm going to create HTML Table with this

```
<style>
table th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

    .cstm{
        padding-top:25px;
        background-color:white;
    }
</style>

<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th width="20%">No.</th>
            <?php foreach($fields as $header) { ?><th width="20%"><?=$header;?></th><?php } ?> //The array from above...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $no = 0;
            if($hasil != ""){
                foreach($hasil as $hsl)
                    {$no++;
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td width="20%"><?=$no;?></td>
            <?php foreach($fields as $header => $key) { ?>
                <td data-original-title="<?=currency($hsl->Customer);?> - <?=currency($hsl->$key);?>" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" class= 'ygdiganti' <?php if($hsl->$key == "") {echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";} ?> width="20%"><?=currency($hsl->$key);?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
                }?>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I'm able create the table with from my script. But I'm missing this part `[1] => 01/08/2016`.

Example result:

```
Customer    01/07/2016  02/07/2016  03/07/2016  04/07/2016  05/07/2016  06/07/2016  07/07/2016  08/07/2016  09/07/2016  10/07/2016  11/07/2016  12/07/2016  13/07/2016  14/07/2016  15/07/2016  16/07/2016  17/07/2016  18/07/2016  19/07/2016  20/07/2016  21/07/2016  22/07/2016  23/07/2016  24/07/2016  25/07/2016  26/07/2016  27/07/2016  28/07/2016  29/07/2016  30/07/2016  31/07/2016
K-LFATR 9826550 23215880    17859700    13272850    NULL    2108900 7356570 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5547920 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9550809 NULL    NULL    NULL    7479130 9869629 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

and here is the screenshot
[image]

So can you guys tell me why `[1] => 01/08/2016` is missing ?

Ok. after I check the source via browser `ctrl+u`. I'm able to see this part

```
<th width="20%">Customer</th>
<th width="20%">01/08/2016</th>
<th width="20%">02/08/2016</th>
```

After i delete `<th width="20%">No.</th>` and `<td width="20%"><?=$no;?></td>` i can see the missing coloumn. But now i missing the `second coloumn`

I have put it in jsfiddle. And it working fine (if the table only) https://jsfiddle.net/kgokL5zw/

Comment: Please show your DataTables initialization code, maybe you have second column hidden?

Comment: I just simply do this `$('#tbl').DataTable({"scrollX": true});`

Comment: I don't see issues with your code except that  you use `td` in `thead` section instead of `th`.

Comment: put `$no++;` after  `<td width="20%"><?=$no;?></td>`

Comment: @Gyrocode.com i change it to th then the result is same :(

Comment: <td style="display:block !important"> </td>

Comment: @blacmoon it makes my table look weird

Comment: View the source of the produced HTML, save it on http://pastebin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link with us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove this part

```
table th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the increment `$no++;` before the foreach closing.

Comment: May be your css or js will hiding it...just echo the $arr[1] separately...